# Not allowed to request resource (fetch error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, fetch

I'm trying to hosting my Express server on my personal computer because it needs Linux + Wine (for building commands). And for using him, I've opened my ports, and I can access to my Express page normally, but if I try to fetch the URL from the Express app, it won't work.

**Here's the errors** : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiuIZ.jpg

**Here's the code of my Express app** : https://hastebin.com/mihizegatu.typescript

**Warning** I've tried to publish my Express app on Heroku, and I can fetch it. But if I fetch my Express app from my personal computer, it won't works (errors upper).

**Do you have an idea of why it doesn't work ?**

Thanks in advance,

Corentin de Maupeou

Comment: It looks like you are trying to fetch the page on a different domain. This often fails due to [cross origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) restrictions. You should be able to fetch the page if you are on the express app's domain.

Comment: How can I find the Express app's domain ? My URL used is : http://xxx.xxx.xxx:5000, does I need another URL ?

Comment: Fetch calls on the xxx.xxx.xxx:5000 site will work, but on any other site they will fail unless you add cross origin resource sharing.

Comment: So if I try to host it on a node server service, normally it'll works ?

Comment: Maybe? Are you making the fetch request **from your own server**? If so, then yes, it will work. If you are making the request from some other website's server then no.